# My scanf function isn't working inside of the if function

Tags: c

When I try to run the scanf inside of the if function after entering either 'a' or 'b', it immediately runs and exits the program without getting input. Is there a way to fix it so the scanf works inside of the if and else if functions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int top=-1;
int word;


char stack_string[100];
void push(char word);
char pop(void);
int main()
{
    char input;
    char str[100];
    int i;
    printf("press [a] for palindrome check, [b] for string reversal:");
    scanf("%c", &input);

    if (input == 'b'){
        printf("Input a string: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
            push(str[i]);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
            str[i]=pop();
        printf("Reversed String is: %s\n",str);
    }
    else if(input == 'a'){
        char str[100];
        int count = 0;
        printf("Input a string: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", str);

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            push(str[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if (str[i]==pop())
            count++;
        }

        if (count == strlen(str))
            printf("%s is a palindrome\n", str);
        else
            printf("%s is not a palindrome\n", str);

    }

    return 0;
}

void push(char word)
{
    top=top+1;
    stack_string[top]=word;
}

 char pop()
{
    word = stack_string[top];
    top=top-1;
    return word;
}
```

Comment: You need a `getchar()` on line 20.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", str);` --> `scanf(" %99[^\n]", str);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", str);
      ^^^
    Whitespace
```

instead of

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
```

For more information, refer [this](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps012a/Fall98/faq/scanfQ.html) link.

Comment: Question why two white space needed infront of scanf?

Comment: `s`  is quite meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `scanf()`. The terminal sends your application a full line at a time, but `scanf()` only consumes the parts it needs, i.e. one character in the case of `%c` or just all the digits in case of `%d`. The rest is left in the input buffer, where the following `scanf()` get them. That causes the user's input and what the program receives to be somewhat "out of sync".

It's better to read full lines at a time, with `fgets()` or `getline()`, and then parse whatever you want from them. E.g.:

```
#define LINELEN 255 
char line[LINELEN];
fgets(line, LINELEN, stdin);
int num;
int a = sscanf(line, "%d", &num);
```

Use whatever format string you require on the `sscanf()` and put the whole thing in a function if you like. (`LINELEN` there is of course an arbitrary
limit, but `fgets()` requires *some* limit.)

See also: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html and the [longer explanation](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) linked there.

Answer (score 0):

use scanf like this: `scanf("%s", str)`

Only scanf statements need to be changed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int top=-1;
int word;


char stack_string[100];
void push(char word);
char pop(void);
int main()
{
char input;
char str[100];
int i;
printf("press [a] for palindrome check, [b] for string reversal:");
scanf("%c", &input);

if (input == 'b'){
    printf("Input a string:\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
        push(str[i]);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
        str[i]=pop();
    printf("Reversed String is: %s\n",str);
}
else if(input == 'a'){
    char str[100];
    int count = 0;
    printf("Input a string:\n");
    scanf("%s", str);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        push(str[i]);
    }
 for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i]==pop())
        count++;
    }

    if (count == strlen(str))
        printf("%s is a palindrome\n", str);
    else
        printf("%s is not a palindrome\n", str);

}

    return 0;
}

void push(char word)
{
    top=top+1;
    stack_string[top]=word;
}

 char pop()
{
    word = stack_string[top];
    top=top-1;
    return word;
}
```